# How to inject $stateParams into state resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been working on some code for a project and have run into a problem with using $stateParams. I am trying to inject a item name into my service through a resolve but it keeps coming up with undefined. I realized I need $stateParams to define it but I can't seem to inject $stateParams into the service. Here is my code and the error, thank you in advance.

Error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=MenuAppX&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20%24stateParams%20is%20not%20defined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20RoutesConfig%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fsrc%2Froutes.js%3A30%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A44%3A357)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A237)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A376%0A%20%20%20%20at%20p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A7)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A332)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20xe%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A1)
at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:43
at p (angular.min.js:8)
at g (angular.min.js:42)
at gb (angular.min.js:46)
at c (angular.min.js:22)
at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
at xe (angular.min.js:21)
at angular.min.js:333
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

State

```
.state('items', {
    url: '/menuItems/{itemId}',
    templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/items.template.html',
    params: {$stateParams, itemId: null},
    controller: 'itemsXController as itemsX',
    resolve: {
      itemsResult: ['MenuDataService, $stateParams', function 
      (MenuDataService, itemId, $stateParams) {
        return MenuDataService.getItemsForCategory($stateParams.itemId);
      }]
   }
})
```

Service

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('data')
  .service('MenuDataService', MenuDataService)
  .constant('categoryBasePath', "https://davids-
restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json?category=");

  MenuDataService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', '$timeout','categoryBasePath'];
  function MenuDataService($http, $q, $timeout, categoryBasePath) {
var service = this;

service.getAllCategory = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var categoriesResult =  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: ('https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json'),
  });
  $timeout(function () {
    deferred.resolve(categoriesResult);
  }, 800);
  return deferred.promise;
}
service.getItemsForCategory = function(itemId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  console.log(itemId);
  var itemsResult =  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: ('https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json?category=L'),
  });
  $timeout(function () {
    deferred.resolve(itemsResult);
  }, 800);
  console.log(deferred.promise);
  return deferred.promise;
}
  };
})();
```

Template(the one calling the state)

```
<a ui-sref="items">This Page works</a>
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="item in categoriesX.categories"  ui-sref="items({itemId: 
categoriesX.categories[$index].short_name})">
{{ categoriesX.categories[$index].name }}
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: remove `stateParam` inside `params` like `params: { itemId: null},`

Comment: the number of parameters being passed into your function don't match.  `['MenuDataService, $stateParams', function 
      (MenuDataService, itemId, $stateParams) {`; you have 3 parameters in the function, but only two in the array.

Answer (score 1):

remove `itemid` from the resolve function

change this

```
 resolve: {
      itemsResult: ['MenuDataService, $stateParams', function 
      (MenuDataService, itemId, $stateParams) {
        return MenuDataService.getItemsForCategory($stateParams.itemId);
      }]
   }
```

to this

```
 resolve: {
      itemsResult: ['MenuDataService, $stateParams', function 
      (MenuDataService, $stateParams) {
        return MenuDataService.getItemsForCategory($stateParams.itemId);
      }]
   }
```

Comment: Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=MenuDataService%2C%20%24stateParamsProvider%20%3C-%20MenuDataService%2C%20%24stateParams)
_defaultErrorHandler @ angular-ui-router.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ angular-ui-router.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:136
$digest @ angular.min.js:147
$apply @ angular.min.js:150
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:22
invoke @ angular.min.js:44
c @ angular.min.js:22
Uc @ angular.min.js:22
xe @ angular.min.js:21
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:3

Comment: 33 b @ angular.min.js:38

Comment: Here is the important part:

Comment: Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=MenuDataService%2C%20%24stateParamsProvider%20%3C-%20MenuDataService%2C%20%24stateParams)

Answer (score 0):

```
    .state('items', {
    url: '/menuItems/{itemId}',
   templateUrl: 'src/MenuApp/template/items.template.html',
   params: { itemId: null},
  controller: 'itemsXController as itemsX',
   resolve: {
  itemsResult: ['MenuDataService, $stateParams', function 
  (MenuDataService, itemId, $stateParams) {
    return MenuDataService.getItemsForCategory($stateParams.itemId);
  }]
   } 
   })
```